# Rails 4 Accessing Join Table Attributes

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a `has_many through` join table setup for a recipe app where `Ingredient` and `Meal` connect through `MealIngredient`. Within `MealIngredient`, I have `meal_id`, `ingredient_id`, and `amount`. My question is: How can I access the `amount` column?

In my recipe view, I loop through the ingredients:

```
@meal.ingredients.each do |i|
```

I can access the properties of the ingredient but not the amount from the `MealIngredient` join record.

I tried using `includes` in the query doing `@meal.ingredients.includes(:meal_ingredients)`, but I'm unsure of how to access the `amount` within the aforementioned loop. When I use `i.inspect`, I don't see any references to the `meal_ingredients` table at all.

Is there some way to access the variable within that loop using `i.amount`?

Thank you in advance for any help!

Answer (score 29, accepted):

**Updated on 08/01/2020 - RPECK**

Struggled with this for months until we found an appropriate solution:

--

[**ActiveRecord Association Extensions**](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#association-extensions)

The problem you have is that Rails will just use the [`foreign_keys`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foreign_key) in your join table to load the associative data you need. Unless you actually load the join model directly, it won't give you the ability to access the join attributes

Some foraging lead us to `ActiveRecord Association Extensions` - a way to access the intermediary data in between different ActiveRecord Associations (using a collection called `proxy_association`). This will allow you to access the extra attributes from the join model, appending them to your "original" model:

```
#app/models/ingredient.rb
class Ingredient < ActiveRecord::Base
   attr_accessor :amount #-> need a setter/getter
end

#app/models/meal.rb
class Meal < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :meal_ingredients
   has_many :ingredients, { -> extending: IngredientAmount }, through: :meal_ingredients
end

#app/models/concerns/ingerdient_amount.rb
module IngredientAmount

    # => Load
    # => Triggered whenever module is invoked (allows us to populate response data)
    # => #<Method: ActiveRecord::Relation#load(&block) c:/Dev/Apps/pwinty-integration/.bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/activerecord-6.0.2.1/lib/active_record/relation.rb:614>
    def load(&block)

       # => This is called from the following reference - if you want to dig deeper, you can use method(:exec_queries).source_location
       # => c:/Dev/Apps/pwinty-integration/.bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/activerecord-6.0.2.1/lib/active_record/association_relation.rb:42
      unless loaded?
        exec_queries do |record|
          record.assign_attributes({amount: items[record.id]}) if items[record.id].present?
        end
      end

    end

    # Load
    # Deprecated with AR 6.0
    #def load
    #   amounts.each do |amount|
    #       proxy_association.target << amount
    #   end
    #end

    #Private
    private

    #Amounts
    # Not needed after AR 6.0
    #def amounts
    #   return_array = []
    #   through_collection.each_with_index do |through,i|
    #       associate = through.send(reflection_name)
    #       associate.assign_attributes({amount: items[i]}) if items[i].present?
    #       return_array.concat Array.new(1).fill( associate )
    #   end
    #   return_array
    #end

    #######################
    #      Variables      #
    #######################

    #Association
    def reflection_name
        proxy_association.source_reflection.name
    end

    #Foreign Key
    def through_source_key
        proxy_association.reflection.source_reflection.foreign_key
    end

    #Primary Key
    def through_primary_key
         proxy_association.reflection.through_reflection.active_record_primary_key
    end

    #Through Name
    def through_name
        proxy_association.reflection.through_reflection.name
    end

    #Through
    def through_collection
        proxy_association.owner.send through_name
    end

    #Captions
    def items
        #through_collection.map(&:amount)
        through_collection.pluck(through_source_key, :amount).map{ |id, amount| { id => amount } }.inject(:merge) #-> { id: record, id: record }
    end

    #Target
    # This no longer works with AR 6.0+
    #def target_collection
    #   #load_target
    #   proxy_association.target
    #end

end
```

This should append the `amount` attribute to your `ingredient` objects now, allowing you to perform:

```
@meal = Meal.find 1
@meal.ingredients.each do |ingredient|
   ingredient.amount
end
```

Comment: Awesome, thank you for the detailed answer and explanation! I like this approach better since the end result makes the most sense in the views and the logic is kept out of the way in a concern.

Comment: It's truly a remarkable piece of work - I will be making into a gem in due course :D Let me know how it works for you - might have some issues or whatever maybe

Comment: How to update "amount" in this example? This is working fine but I also need to update the value.

Comment: How are you updating the value? You're using a standard pattern of `fields_for` or not? If you write a question, post the link here and I'll write an answer for you if you like

Comment: Richard...two years later I am asking that update value question you were interested in answering. Here it is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39010893/how-do-i-save-and-update-attributes-in-a-join-table-in-rails-4-hmt-association

Comment: Looks exactly the solution I'd like to implement. Very clean - unfortunately, I keep getting nil values no matter what. Using byebug - it doesn't even load the attributes (calling load). Do I miss anything? Note I am on Rails 5 @RichardPeck

Comment: Haven't tested on Rails 5 - do you have a repo I could look at?

Comment: Also we can go to chat about this, I value the code and want it to work

Comment: @GeorgKeferböck Anything come of the last 3 comments above? I'm on Rails 4, but am getting nil values as well, and not seeing the load() method called at all.

Comment: We can talk directly about it you want - rpeck@fronlineutilities.co.uk

Comment: Too much work for a task that requires a simple `collection_check_boxes` form helper with HABTM associations. I would rather use a controller to update the HMT records than go through this mess. This cannot be the way for such a common task like update an HMT quantity within the associated tables forms.

Answer (score 30):

In this case, you should loop through the `meal_ingredients` association. You should eager load the `ingredients` association to reduce db queries.

```
@meal.meal_ingredients.includes(:ingredient).each do |meal_ingredient|
  puts meal_ingredient.amount
  puts meal_ingredient.ingredient.name
end
```

**UPDATE**

This update came after Rich Peck's answer but I think there's a simpler way to achieve what he did.

```
@meal.ingredients.select('ingredients.*, meal_ingredients.amount').each do |ingredient|
  puts ingredient.amount
  puts ingredient.name
end
```

Comment: Yeah I was just trying out your updated solution, found it doesn't typecast (eg, boolean columns come back as 0 or 1), so this could prove to be problematic for some