# How do I save and update attributes in a join table in Rails 4 HMT association?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, has-many-through

I have a `has_many` through join table setup for a recipe app where `Ingredient` and `Meal` connect through `MealIngredient`. Within `MealIngredient`, I have `meal_id`, `ingredient_id`, and `amount`.

My question is: How can I save and update the amount column in the meal form?

My form field for adding an ingredient looks like this:

```
<% Ingredient.all.each do |ingredient| %>
  <label>
    <%= check_box_tag "meal[ingredient_ids][]", ingredient.id, f.object.ingredients.include?(ingredient) %>
    <%= ingredient.name %>
  </label>
  <br />
<% end %>
```

How do I save the amount for each ingredient?

I am referencing this question found here: [Rails 4 Accessing Join Table Attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25235025/rails-4-accessing-join-table-attributes)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I made a demo for you: http://meals-test2.herokuapp.com/new
[image]

--

If you're using a form, you need to use [`fields_for`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-fields_for) and edit it that way:

```
#app/controllers/meals_controller.rb
class MealsController < ApplicationController
  def edit
    @meal = Meal.find params[:id]
  end

  private

  def meal_params
    params.require(:meal).permit(meal_ingredient_attributes: [:amount])
  end
end

#app/views/meals/edit.html.erb
<%= form_for @meal do |f| %>
  <%= fields_for :meal_ingredients do |i| %>
      <%= f.object.ingredient.name #-> meal_ingredient belongs_to ingredient %>
      <%= i.number_field :amount %>
  <% end %>
  <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

The above will output a list of ingredients *for the meal* and allow you to input the "amount" value.

As for checkboxes, I'd have to make a demo app to see if I can get that working. I can do this if you feel it necessary.

---

Another way is with `has_and_belongs_to_many`:

```
#app/models/meal.rb
class Meal < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :ingredients do
     def amount #-> @meal.ingredients.first.amount
        ...........
     end
  end
end

#app/models/ingredient.rb
class Ingredient < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :meals
end
```

This way, you'll be able to add as many `meals` / `ingredients` as required, allowing you to find the "amount" with `@meal.ingredients.where(ingredients: {id: "x" }).size`. You could also make a method to simplify it (above).

You wouldn't need to use `fields_for` for this:

```
#app/controllers/meals_controller.rb
class MealsController < ApplicationController
  def new
     @meal = Meal.new
  end
  def edit
     @meal = Meal.find params[:id]
  end

  def update
     @meal = Meal.find params[:id]
     @meal.save
  end

  def create
     @meal = Meal.new meal_params
     @meal.save
  end

  private

  def meal_params
    params.require(:meal).permit(ingredient_ids: [])
  end
end
```

Because the HABTM record uses the `has_many` association in your model, it provides you with the [`collection_singular_ids`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-has_many) method. This allows you to override the associated data without `fields_for`:

```
#app/views/meals/new.html.erb
<%= form_for @meal do |f| %>
  <%= f.collection_check_boxes :ingredient_ids, Ingredient.all, :id, :name %>
  <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

If you wanted to add extra ingredients, you'd need to create JS to duplicate the checkbox element. This will then allow you to submit *multiple* `ids` to the controller, which will just insert them blindly into the db.

This method *overrides* the ingredients list, and only works if you don't have any uniqueness constraints on the habtm association / table.

Comment: The link no longer works, would you be able to re-host, or at least point to your source code somewhere?

Comment: The account got suspended because I used a temporary email. I'll reupload in a minute for you